# PostgreSQL with recursive -> prevent deadlocks/recursion

Tags: postgresql

Hi i want to select objects with postgres recursive. But i cannot guarantee that every data in the database is correct. So i'ts not impossible that an object has for example itself as parent id.

Is it possible to stop when an object already exists? What i've tried:

```
with recursive sumthis(myobjectid,parent_myobjectid) as (
    select myobjectid, parent_myobjectid
    from myobjectentity
    where myobjectid = 243358
    union all
    select C.myobjectid, C.parent_myobjectid
    from sumthis P
    inner join myobjectentity C on P.myobjectid = C.parent_myobjectid AND (P.myobjectid NOT IN (SELECT myobjectid FROM sumthis))

)

SELECT * FROM myobjectentity WHERE myobjectid IN (select myobjectid from sumthis)
```

AND

```
with recursive sumthis(myobjectid,parent_myobjectid) as (
    select myobjectid, parent_myobjectid
    from myobjectentity
    where myobjectid = 243358
    union all
    select C.myobjectid, C.parent_myobjectid
    from sumthis P
    inner join myobjectentity C on P.myobjectid = C.parent_myobjectid
    Limit 100

)

SELECT * FROM myobjectentity WHERE myobjectid IN (select myobjectid from sumthis)
```

Comment: This is a special case of non-repeating directed graph traversal. Thankfully as you discovered, recursive CTEs (used right) help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the answer is reasy, i just had to change

```
union all
```

to

```
union
```